# Excel spread sheet to html

Tags: xml, excel, xslt

I have an xml - Excel spread sheet - as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook  xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
   <Styles>
  <Style ss:ID="Style-[FontFamily: Name=Aharoni]-11-True-False-NoneColor-String-False-Right">
     <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" />
     <Font ss:FontName="Aharoni" ss:Size="11" ss:Bold="1" />
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="Style-[FontFamily: Name=Aharoni]-11-True-False-NoneColor-Number-False-Right">
     <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" />
     <Font ss:FontName="Aharoni" ss:Size="11" ss:Bold="1" />
     <NumberFormat ss:Format="#,##0.00" />
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="Style-[FontFamily: Name=Aharoni]-11-True-False-RedAndGreenStyle-Number-False-Right">
     <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" />
     <Font ss:FontName="Aharoni" ss:Size="11" ss:Bold="1" />
     <NumberFormat ss:Format="[Color 10][&gt;0]#,##0.00;[Black][=0]#,##0.00;[Red]#,##0.00" />
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="Style-[FontFamily: Name=Aharoni]-11-True-False-GreenStyle-Number-False-Right">
     <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" />
     <Font ss:FontName="Aharoni" ss:Size="11" ss:Bold="1" ss:Color="#00B000" />
     <NumberFormat ss:Format="#,##0.00" />
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="Style-[FontFamily: Name=Aharoni]-11-True-False-RedStyle-Number-False-Right">
     <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" />
     <Font ss:FontName="Aharoni" ss:Size="11" ss:Bold="1" ss:Color="#FF0000" />
     <NumberFormat ss:Format="#,##0.00" />
  </Style>
   </Styles>
   <Worksheet ss:Name="PAPERS" ss:RightToLeft="1">
  <Table>
     <Column ss:Width="87.49609375" />
     <Column ss:Width="50" />
     <Column ss:Width="92.04541015625" />
     <Column ss:Width="94.19384765625" />
     <Column ss:Width="52.18115234375" />
     <Column ss:Width="50" />
     <Column ss:Width="53.09423828125" />
     <Column ss:Width="141.99658203125" />
     <Column ss:Width="55.24267578125" />
     <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="Style-[FontFamily: Name=Aharoni]-11-True-False-NoneColor-String-False-Right">
           <Data ss:Type="String">COL1</Data>
           <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Titles" />
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="Style-[FontFamily: Name=Aharoni]-11-True-False-NoneColor-String-False-Right">
           <Data ss:Type="String">COL2</Data>
           <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Titles" />
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="Style-[FontFamily: Name=Aharoni]-11-True-False-NoneColor-String-False-Right">
           <Data ss:Type="String">COL3</Data>
           <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Titles" />
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="Style-[FontFamily: Name=Aharoni]-11-True-False-NoneColor-String-False-Right">
           <Data ss:Type="String">COL4</Data>
           <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Titles" />
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="Style-[FontFamily: Name=Aharoni]-11-True-False-NoneColor-String-False-Right">
           <Data ss:Type="String">COL5</Data>
           <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Titles" />
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="Style-[FontFamily: Name=Aharoni]-11-True-False-NoneColor-String-False-Right">
           <Data ss:Type="String">COL6</Data>
           <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Titles" />
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="Style-[FontFamily: Name=Aharoni]-11-True-False-NoneColor-String-False-Right">
           <Data ss:Type="String">COL7</Data>
           <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Titles" />
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="Style-[FontFamily: Name=Aharoni]-11-True-False-NoneColor-String-False-Right">
           <Data ss:Type="String">COL8</Data>
           <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Titles" />
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="Style-[FontFamily: Name=Aharoni]-11-True-False-NoneColor-String-False-Right">
           <Data ss:Type="String">COL9</Data>
           <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Titles" />
        </Cell>
     </Row>
     <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="Style-[FontFamily: Name=Aharoni]-11-True-False-NoneColor-String-False-Right">
           <Data ss:Type="String">CELL1</Data>
           <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Titles" />
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="Style-[FontFamily: Name=Aharoni]-11-True-False-NoneColor-Number-False-Right">
           <Data ss:Type="Number">3040</Data>
           <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Titles" />
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="Style-[FontFamily: Name=Aharoni]-11-True-False-RedAndGreenStyle-Number-False-Right">
           <Data ss:Type="Number">-0.750897812602024</Data>
           <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Titles" />
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="Style-[FontFamily: Name=Aharoni]-11-True-False-NoneColor-String-False-Right">
           <Data ss:Type="String">CELL4</Data>
           <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Titles" />
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="Style-[FontFamily: Name=Aharoni]-11-True-False-NoneColor-Number-False-Right">
           <Data ss:Type="Number">3063</Data>
           <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Titles" />
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="Style-[FontFamily: Name=Aharoni]-11-True-False-NoneColor-String-False-Right">
           <Data ss:Type="String">CELL6</Data>
           <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Titles" />
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="Style-[FontFamily: Name=Aharoni]-11-True-False-NoneColor-String-False-Right">
           <Data ss:Type="String">CELL7</Data>
           <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Titles" />
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="Style-[FontFamily: Name=Aharoni]-11-True-False-NoneColor-String-False-Right">
           <Data ss:Type="String">CELL8</Data>
           <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Titles" />
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="Style-[FontFamily: Name=Aharoni]-11-True-False-NoneColor-String-False-Right">
           <Data ss:Type="String" />
           <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Titles" />
        </Cell>           
     </Row>
 </Table>
  <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
     <Panes />
     <DisplayRightToLeft>True</DisplayRightToLeft>
     <PageSetup>
        <Layout Orientation="Portrait" />
     </PageSetup>
  </WorksheetOptions>
  <Names>
     <NamedRange ss:Name="Print_Titles" ss:RefersTo="=PAPERS!R1" />
  </Names>
   </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

I want to transform it to An html by using xslt transform, and i don't know how to transform it to design it as it's style, and how to set width of columns, and set the direction of any cell by worksheetoption?

My first xslt (i know that its not good..):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" >
<xsl:template match="Workbook/Worksheet/Table">
<HTML>
   <BODY>   
  <TABLE border='1' style='table-layout:fixed' width='600'>       
     <xsl:for-each select="Row">
        <TR>   
  <xsl:for-each select="Cell">
 <TD><xsl:value-of select='Data'/></TD>
  </xsl:for-each>
        </TR>
     </xsl:for-each>
  </TABLE>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing: get the data into your table. For this, you need to respect the **namespaces** used by the source document. Try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
exclude-result-prefixes="ss">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <table border='1'>       
        <xsl:for-each select="ss:Workbook/ss:Worksheet/ss:Table/ss:Row">
            <tr>   
                <xsl:for-each select="ss:Cell">
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select='ss:Data'/>
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Next step: add the column widths to the table:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
exclude-result-prefixes="ss">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <table border='1'>  
        <colgroup>
            <xsl:for-each select="ss:Workbook/ss:Worksheet/ss:Table/ss:Column">
                <col width="{@ss:Width}"/>
            </xsl:for-each> 
        </colgroup>
        <xsl:for-each select="ss:Workbook/ss:Worksheet/ss:Table/ss:Row">
            <tr>   
                <xsl:for-each select="ss:Cell">
                    <td> 
                        <xsl:value-of select='ss:Data'/>
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Finally, we're going to link each cell with its style and get the alignment:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
exclude-result-prefixes="ss">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="style" match="ss:Style" use="@ss:ID" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <table border='1'>  
        <colgroup>
            <xsl:for-each select="ss:Workbook/ss:Worksheet/ss:Table/ss:Column">
                <col width="{@ss:Width}"/>
            </xsl:for-each> 
        </colgroup>
        <xsl:for-each select="ss:Workbook/ss:Worksheet/ss:Table/ss:Row">
            <tr>   
                <xsl:for-each select="ss:Cell">
                    <td align="{key('style', @ss:StyleID)/ss:Alignment/@ss:Horizontal}">
                        <xsl:value-of select='ss:Data'/>
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This way you can fetch more style attributes and use them. Alternatively, you could generate an internal CSS stylesheet and point your table elements to it.

Note also that you can export an HTML document from Excel and save yourself a lot of work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, i tried it, but seems that the column width isn't settings, also for alignment? how to can i achieve it?

Comment: @DavidMichaeli "*seems that the column width isn't settings, also for alignment?*" How are you testing this?

Comment: 2 ways - by write little program in c# that give the result - or by this web site:     http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog, i see it..

Comment: @DavidMichaeli www.w3schools.com is not a good test tool; please observe the results here: http://xsltransform.net/6qM2e2m